# Android SupportFragment returns Map Object as null

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I am displaying a map in my android application like this:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

The fragment is defined like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  map:cameraTargetLat="28.635308"
  map:cameraTargetLng="77.224960"
  map:uiCompass="true"
  map:uiRotateGestures="true"
  map:uiScrollGestures="true"
  map:uiTiltGestures="true"
  map:uiZoomControls="true"
  map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

The problem is on some mobiles it is working fine while on others(android 2.2,2.3) it is not working. The map object is null in these cases. 
To me it appears that the reason behind this is that google play services is not installed on these mobiles. Am i correct, if yes what is the possible workaround.

Comment: did you check the availability google play services before initializing gogolemap

Comment: @Raghunandan how do i do that? If it is not available how to display the map?

Comment: check the docs there is a sample code there